# numpy.dot how to calculate 1-D array with 2-D array

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

The numpy.dot docstring says:

> For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication, and for 1-D arrays to inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation). For N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last of b

But it doesn't illustrate how numpy.dot calculate 1-D array with 2-D array.So how does Numpy handle 1-D array(vector) with 2-D array(matrix)?

I have make some test:

```
In [27]: a
Out[27]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

In [28]: b
Out[28]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [29]: np.dot(a,b)
Out[29]: array([ 5, 14, 23])

In [30]: np.dot(a, b.reshape(-1,1))
Out[30]: 
array([[ 5],
       [14],
       [23]])

In [31]: np.dot(a, b.reshape(-1,1)).ravel() # same as np.dot(a,b)
Out[31]: array([ 5, 14, 23])

In [32]: np.dot(b,a)
Out[32]: array([15, 18, 21])

In [33]: np.dot(b.reshape(1,-1), a)
Out[33]: array([[15, 18, 21]])

In [34]: np.dot(b.reshape(1,-1), a).ravel() # same as np.dot(b,a)
Out[34]: array([15, 18, 21])
```

The above tests indecate that numpy.dot can handle 1-D array with 2-D array. Is it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 1-d array and a 2-d array are handled as a matrix-vector (or vector-matrix) product. The implementation in fact uses the BLAS `*gemv` functions to handle this case for floating-point inputs.

Comment: Thx for your Fortran BLAS explanation!

Comment: @Honghe.Wu Actually it's CBLAS that is being called.

Comment: @larsmans: it actually depends on how numpy was compiled. Typically, you'd prefer Intel MKL linked numpy, which is readily available for Windows, and can be obtained for various Linux distributions if you are not commercially developing something.

Comment: @rubenvb: yes, and if you link to another CBLAS implementation, it will call that. I was referring to the API, not any particular implementation of it.

Answer (score 5):

There's only one case not explicitly described in the documentation, but kind of hinted, which is how to apply to a 2D and a 1D inputs the rule:

> it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-to-last of
>   b

In your case, when you do `np.dot(a, b)`, there is no "second-to-last" axis of `b`. What numpy does then, is to settle for the last. So it does the sum product of every row of `a` with `b`, as your test readily shows.

All of your other examples fit into the above rule.